# socket.io multiplexing connection by refreshing client page

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have a problem with socket.io

when I refresh the client page, sockets are increased.

for example, this is the sample code

```
var express = require("express"),
    http = require('http'),
    app = express(),
    server = http.createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    var doc=`
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
            <script>
                var socket = io();
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>hello!</h1>
        </body>
    </html>
    `
    res.send(doc);
    io.on("connection",function(socket){
        console.log("connected!")
    })
})
```

on the first connection, server log has 1 "connected!" message.

and refreshing the client page, the console.log() fired double. so log has 3 "connected!" messages

refreshing one more it fires triple -> 6 connected messages

and next quadriple!

I don't know why connections are multiplexed. could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event handler for the server-side socket you declared needs to be registered just once.

```
var express = require("express"),
http = require('http'),
app = express(),
server = http.createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.on("connection",function(socket){
    console.log("connected!")
})

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
var doc=`
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
        <script>
            var socket = io();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>hello!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
`
res.send(doc);
})
```

Every time a request comes in from the browser, you were adding a new **anonymous** function as an event listener to any socket opened.

Comment: thanks a lot!  what if I need to access argument 'req' in socket?

Comment: The "connection" event gives you a reference (in the callback) to a live socket with a connected browser instance. You need to store the reference on your server - in an appropriate data structure (object with keys or arrays etc) - so you can use it inside other server functions such as your request handlers. Keep in mind that there is no implicit relationship between request events and events in the sockets.